# Авто генерирование базы данных из модели Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

Есть модель и конфигурация дял spring. Нужно чтобы автоматически создавалась база из модели. Но она не создается не смотря на то что hbm2ddl.auto и annotatedClasses установлены(ПРи попытке сохранить что-нибудь в базу выбрасывается ошибка что таблица не создана). 
Есть идеи что можно сделать? Зарание благодарю.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "advertisement", schema = "public")
public class Advertisement {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_advertisement")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
@NotNull
private String name;

@Column(name = "picture_url")
@NotNull
@URL
private String pictureUrl;

@Column(name = "link_url")
@NotNull
@URL
private String linkUrl;

@Column(name = "state")
@Pattern(regexp = "(Active|Stopped|Pending)")
private String state = "Stopped";

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_category", nullable = false)
private Category category;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "add", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Valid
private Set<Statistic> statistics;
//setters gettesr
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "category", schema = "public")

public class Category {

@Id
@Column(name = "id_category")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
@NotNull
private String name;

@Column(name = "state")
@Pattern(regexp = "(Active|Stopped|Pending)")
private String state = "Stopped";

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Advertisement> ads;
//setters getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "statistic", schema = "public")
public class Statistic {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_statistic", nullable = false)
private int id;

@Column(name = "date")
@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date date;

@Column(name = "clicks")
@NotNull
private int clicks;

@Column(name = "paid")
@NotNull
private int paid ;
//setters getters
}



   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="sptool.managers"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="sptool.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="sptool.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="sptool.model"/>


<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>sptool.model.Advertisement</value>
            <value>sptool.model.Category</value>
            <value>sptool.model.Statistic</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

Логи:

```
    2016-06-13 15:42:40.172  INFO 17462 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
2016-06-13 15:42:40.177  INFO 17462 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-06-13 15:42:40.180  INFO 17462 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-06-13 15:42:40.480  INFO 17462 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2016-06-13 15:42:40.492  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-06-13 15:42:40.640  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2016-06-13 15:42:40.644  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-06-13 15:42:41.239  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@32fa809f: startup date [Mon Jun 13 15:42:41 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-06-13 15:42:41.240  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [bean_configuration.xml]
2016-06-13 15:42:41.507  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionAdvisor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]]
2016-06-13 15:42:41.507  INFO 17462 --- [           main] a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=transactionalEventListenerFactory,declaringClass=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
2016-06-13 15:42:41.532  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
2016-06-13 15:42:41.667  INFO 17462 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2016-06-13 15:42:41.668  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-06-13 15:42:41.676  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2016-06-13 15:42:41.677  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-06-13 15:42:41.726  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@16da476c: startup date [Mon Jun 13 15:42:41 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-06-13 15:42:41.727  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [bean_configuration.xml]
2016-06-13 15:42:42.023  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionAdvisor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]]
2016-06-13 15:42:42.024  INFO 17462 --- [           main] a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=transactionalEventListenerFactory,declaringClass=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
2016-06-13 15:42:42.040  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
2016-06-13 15:42:42.131  INFO 17462 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2016-06-13 15:42:42.132  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-06-13 15:42:42.141  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2016-06-13 15:42:42.142  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-06-13 15:42:42.225  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager      : Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@5234b61a] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2016-06-13 15:42:42.545  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-06-13 15:42:42.565  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager      : Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@5aa76ad2] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2016-06-13 15:42:42.738  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-06-13 15:42:42.750  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager      : Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@2871ac91] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2016-06-13 15:42:42.878  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-06-13 15:42:43.076  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4b9e255: startup date [Mon Jun 13 15:42:36 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-06-13 15:42:43.170  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/category/{id}/advertisement/],methods=[POST],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.AdvertisementController.createAd(int,sptool.model.Advertisement)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.172  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/advertisement/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.AdvertisementController.getAdById(int)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.172  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/category/{id}/advertisement],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.AdvertisementController.getAdsFromCategory(int,java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.172  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/advertisement/{id}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Void> sptool.controller.AdvertisementController.removeAd(int)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.173  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/advertisement/{id}/statistic],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.StatisticController.createStatistic(int,sptool.model.Statistic)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.174  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/advertisement/{id}/general],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.StatisticController.generalStatistic(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.174  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/category/{id}/statistic],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.StatisticController.generalStatisticAboutCategory(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.175  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/category/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.CategoryController.getCategory(int)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.176  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/category/],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.CategoryController.listAllCategories()
2016-06-13 15:42:43.176  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/category/],methods=[POST],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> sptool.controller.CategoryController.createCategory(sptool.model.Category)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.176  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/category/{id}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.CategoryController.removeCategory(int)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.176  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/category/{id}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity sptool.controller.CategoryController.updateCategory(int,sptool.model.Category)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.181  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.181  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.212  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-06-13 15:42:43.213  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-06-13 15:42:43.260  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-06-13 15:42:43.344  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2016-06-13 15:42:43.644  INFO 17462 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-06-13 15:42:43.810  INFO 17462 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-06-13 15:42:43.838  INFO 17462 --- [           main] sptool.controller.App                    : Started App in 7.667 seconds (JVM running for 8.13)
2016-06-13 15:42:46.400  INFO 17462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-06-13 15:42:46.400  INFO 17462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-06-13 15:42:46.412  INFO 17462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 12 ms
2016-06-13 15:42:46.623  WARN 17462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2016-06-13 15:42:46.623 ERROR 17462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "public.category" does not exist
```

Comment: 1. Проверьте, что вы вообще к базе данных можете подключиться с указанными JDBC URL и пользователем; 2. Вы видимо взяли Spring Boot приложение и скопировали в него кусок XML конфига Spring MVC. XML там вообще не нужен. [Обычно это вот так делается](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database); 3. Чтобы понимать что происходит с приложением [логи нужно снимать в режить DEBUG](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-levels).

Comment: @enzo Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Да смысла нет, что это кому то еще потом поможет. Это не ответ, а рекомендации.

Comment: Посмотрите в логах. Вы подключаетесь к H2
Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
хотя, судя по настройке хибернейта, хотите подключиться к PostgreSQL. Такое может быть, если не сконфигурирован DataSource, по дефолту создается DataSource к H2. Так что создание DataSource с подключением к Postgres и объявлением его в качестве бина может решить вашу проблему

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте, что вы вообще к базе данных можете подключиться с указанными JDBC URL и пользователем;
2. Вы видимо взяли Spring Boot приложение и скопировали в него кусок XML конфига Spring MVC. XML там вообще не нужен. Обычно это вот так делается;
3. Чтобы понимать что происходит с приложением логи нужно снимать в режить DEBUG.

Посмотрите в логах. Вы подключаетесь к H2 Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa' хотя, судя по настройке хибернейта, хотите подключиться к PostgreSQL. Такое может быть, если не сконфигурирован DataSource, по дефолту создается DataSource к H2. Так что создание DataSource с подключением к Postgres и объявлением его в качестве бина может решить вашу проблему